# Kafka Stream throw StreamExpection after supress operator and stream client going to shut down

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

The ErrorMessage like this:

org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Existing internal topic error-span-aggregate-stream-KTABLE-SUPPRESS-STATE-STORE-0000000004-changelog has invalid partitions: expected: 16; actual: 20. Use 'kafka.tools.StreamsResetter' tool to clean up invalid topics before processing
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.InternalTopicManager.validateTopics(InternalTopicManager.java:579) ~[kafka-streams-3.0.1.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.InternalTopicManager.makeReady(InternalTopicManager.java:399) ~[kafka-streams-3.0.1.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ChangelogTopics.setup(ChangelogTopics.java:97) ~[kafka-streams-3.0.1.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsPartitionAssignor.assignTasksToClients(StreamsPartitionAssignor.java:585) ~[kafka-streams-3.0.1.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsPartitionAssignor.assign(StreamsPartitionAssignor.java:397) ~[kafka-streams-3.0.1.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.performAssignment(ConsumerCoordinator.java:640) ~[kafka-clients-3.0.1.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.onJoinLeader(AbstractCoordinator.java:690) ~[kafka-clients-3.0.1.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.access$1000(AbstractCoordinator.java:112) ~[kafka-clients-3.0.1.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$JoinGroupResponseHandler.handle(AbstractCoordinator.java:594) ~[kafka-clients-3.0.1.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$JoinGroupResponseHandler.handle(AbstractCoordinator.java:557) ~[kafka-clients-3.0.1.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$CoordinatorResponseHandler.onSuccess(AbstractCoordinator.java:1184) ~[kafka-clients-3.0.1.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$CoordinatorResponseHandler.onSuccess(AbstractCoordinator.java:1159) ~[kafka-clients-3.0.1.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture$1.onSuccess(RequestFuture.java:206) ~[kafka-clients-3.0.1.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture.fireSuccess(RequestFuture.java:169) ~[kafka-clients-3.0.1.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture.complete(RequestFuture.java:129) ~[kafka-clients-3.0.1.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient$RequestFutureCompletionHandler.fireCompletion(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:602) ~[kafka-clients-3.0.1.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.firePendingCompletedRequests(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:412) ~[kafka-clients-3.0.1.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:297) ~[kafka-clients-3.0.1.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:236) ~[kafka-clients-3.0.1.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollForFetches(KafkaConsumer.java:1297) ~[kafka-clients-3.0.1.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1238) ~[kafka-clients-3.0.1.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1211) ~[kafka-clients-3.0.1.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.pollRequests(StreamThread.java:932) ~[kafka-streams-3.0.1.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.pollPhase(StreamThread.java:885) ~[kafka-streams-3.0.1.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:720) ~[kafka-streams-3.0.1.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:583) ~[kafka-streams-3.0.1.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:555) ~[kafka-streams-3.0.1.jar!/:?]

My Code like this:

KTable<Windowed, MyAggregate> dubboAggregateStream = kStream.groupByKey()
.windowedBy(TimeWindows.ofSizeAndGrace(TEN_SECOND, STREAM_AGGREGATE_THRESHOLD))
.aggregate(MyAggregate::new, this::update(), materialized)
.suppress(untilWindowCloses(new StrictBufferConfigImpl(128 * 1024,128 * 1024 * 1024, EMIT, emptyMap())));

What puzzles me is that after i remove suppress operator，it works fine,like this:
KTable<Windowed, MyAggregate> dubboAggregateStream = kStream.groupByKey()
.windowedBy(TimeWindows.ofSizeAndGrace(TEN_SECOND, STREAM_AGGREGATE_THRESHOLD))
.aggregate(MyAggregate::new, this::update(), materialized);

Could someone help me？Thanks

Comment: The partition num of the input topic set to 16,but why the changelog topic partition actual is 20???

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you ran the streams application before with a different number of partitions. Please follow the advise of the error message and use `StreamsResetter` to delete the changelog topics so that they can be recreated by `KafkaStreams`.